# In target framework 4.5, WPF Dispatcher.Invoke is not allowing to update the Text Block in separate thread

Tags: c#, wpf

Following method is from **mainwindow**, which calls the method **Show()** in the **sub window**. I used Dispatcher.Invoke thread to update the labels in the sub window untill the device search is done, which is working good upto target framework 3.5 and not working in 4.5 framework

```
private void OnShowBTWindow(bool isSrchDev)
        {
            BTMeasure winBTMeasure = new BTMeasure();
            winBTMeasure.Owner = this;
            if (!isSrchDev)
            {
                winBTMeasure.ShowDialog();
            }
            else {
                **winBTMeasure.Show(this);**
                if (AvailableDevices != null)
                {
                    winBTMeasure = null;
                    winBTMeasure = new BTMeasure();
                    winBTMeasure.Owner = this;
                    winBTMeasure.ShowDeviceListWindow(this);
                }
            }
        }
```

Following method is from sub window, which updates the text block in sub window until the device search is completed the window will be appearing which may take 2 seconds to find the devices. Once the DeviceSearch() is true, the sub window will be closed. This code is working good upto target framework 3.5 but not working in the target framework 4.5

```
public void Show(Window owner)
        {
            try
            {
                this.Owner = owner;
                this.Dispatcher.Invoke((Action)(() =>
                {
                    txtHeader.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Hidden;
                    txtbody.Text = "Searching for the device..!!";
                    btnCancel.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Hidden;
                    btnSearchCont.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Hidden;
                    this.Show();
                }));
                if (DeviceSearch())
                {
                    this.Close();
                }
            }
       }
```

Please help provide input in fixing this issue.

Comment: What do you mean code is not working? Are you getting some exception?

Comment: If you want only to show some text and disable Buttons, why just not to use backgroundworker?

Comment: My design is to use a single window for Multiple purpose. Initially there will be a window with button Search, if a user clicks on the search button the window will be closed and again it will be opened with different text message saying "Searching for device". The code with DeviceSearch() will be returned once the search is complete and the "Searching for device" window will be closed. Now my issue is, in target framework 3.5 same code is working and showing the "Searching for the device" text without any issue. but in 4.5 framework the window is open and text block is not loading.

Comment: Background worker also i tried but its not showing the text block in window. But window is open.

Comment: @user2114103 what do you mean by text block? Text "Searching for the device..!!"? If yes, you can use progressChanged

Comment: @Sasha... The above code block is working as per intention in lower target framework like 3.5 but not in 4.5 framework. I may be missing or need to alter something to make it work in 4.5 framework. If i need to use Background worker i need to redesign it again. Please help me after looking into complete workflow of the code.

Answer (score 0):

You should be more specific about what "this issue" is.

That said, I see you are calling "this.Close()" outside of the anonymous method invoked by Dispatcher.Invoke(). Like other GUI object members, that has to be executed on the dispatcher thread as well.

For that matter, I'm not entirely sure it's safe to set the Owner property outside the dispatcher thread. In general, you really should work hard to avoid *any* access of a thread-affinitied object outside that object's owning thread.

Comment: My req is to show a window for period of time untill i get response from -- if (DeviceSearch())-- just to intimate the user that it is searcing or something like that. Once i get the result from the above mentioned condition the window which was in open condition will be closed. Which is working good in 3.5 FW. Same window is getting opened properly in 4.5 FW also but the text block content is missing/ not loading.